# Flatten a numpy ndarray array elements to rows of features

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have a 4D `numpy array` in which each column represents 1 quantity and the rows are a statistics derivatives of the quantities, like.

```
[mean mean mean
 std  std  std
 med  med  med]
```

Let's say column 1 represents `speed` column 2 `acceleration` etc. I would like to flatten each column of the array for all the quantities available into a row of features forming:

```
mean std med mean std med mean std med ...
```

To clarify my concern, I give the following `MWE`:

```
input_shape = (1,3,4)
n_sample =20

X = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(n_sample, )+ input_shape)
X.shape
(20,1,3,4)
```

So the first 2 entiries of X are:

```
X[:2]
array([[[[1, 7, 7, 8],
         [9, 3, 4, 1],
         [1, 1, 7, 1]]],


       [[[2, 8, 9, 4],
         [8, 4, 2, 7],
         [3, 9, 8, 4]]]])
```

The columns represent quantities `q1, q2, q3, q4` and the rows represents the statistics: `mean, std, med` for each of the arrays.

Then I want to flatten these statistics for each quantity to row of features so that the end result is like this:

```
  q1_mean q1_std q1_med q2_mean q2_std q2_med q3_mean q3_std q3_med q4_mean q4_std q4_med
     1      9       1      7      3      1      7       4       7      8      1       1
     2      8       3      8      4      9      9       2       8      4      7       4
```

So each array is a single observation. So I can easily transform to a dataframe, adding appropriate column head(name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this should do what you want:

```
np.transpose(X,(0,1,3,2)).reshape(X.shape[0],-1)
```

Note that transposing axis 2 and 3 is necessary since reshape will be done in a row-major (C-style) order.

Comment: This would actually be a good usecase for `swapaxes`

Comment: Yes, ```swapaxes``` is also a good alternative here to ```transpose```.

Comment: @GilPinsky can you please comment on the ordering of the indexes `(0,1,3,2)`?

Comment: @super_ask Sure. The tuple has 4 indices from 0 to 3 since X has 4 axes. It means that axis 0 in the returned ```ndarray``` will stay axis 0 as in X, axis 1 will stay axis 1 as in X. However, axis 2 in the returned ```ndarray``` will be now axis 3 from X and axis 3 in the returned ```ndarray``` will be axis 2. So essentially, it means you swap axes between axis 2 and axis 3 within the original array, X.

Comment: Interesting, now I understand.